# JSON Exception Unterminated Error in response?

Tags: android, json

in my application am getting response from server as J SON format.At time of parsing,it shows unterminated Error in response.So am not able to parse it.

**My json coding**

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);

        HttpResponse response;

        try {

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.base_url)+ "login?json=");

            Time dtNow = new Time();
            dtNow.setToNow();
            String last_login_ts = dtNow.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

            // Log.v("Login_ts",""+last_login_ts);

            json.put("pmailtxt", "" + et_username.getText().toString());
            json.put("loginpasstxt", "" + et_password.getText().toString());
            json.put("merchant_code", "" + getString(R.string.merchant_code));
            json.put("last_login_ts", "" + last_login_ts);

            // Log.v("Login", ""+json);

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+json, 700).show();

            post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);

            // Checking response
            if (response != null) {

                // get a data
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                String a = json_res_class.convertStreamToString(in);
                Log.v("Response", ""+a);//here am getting response
```

**Here my response error**

```
06-07 16:05:55.132: W/System.err(930): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at  character 5 of [  {"loginSuccess":0,"message":"Wrong username or password"}]
```

How can i rectify this problem,Can any one know please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: for FSM sake! use google translate on `Unterminated array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is kind of clear... the last character of your JSON is missing so your array is not closed. As it is not closed, it can't be parsed.

Moreover, in case of parsing, you should catch the exception.

Comment: sorry am missing that one,at time of copy and past from log cat.

Comment: without more code or anything else, we can't do anything. "Help us to help you"

Answer (score 1):

Look the below code

```
try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            int responsecode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (responsecode == 200) {

                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                resultstring = Util.convertinputStreamToString(in);
            } 

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Check your convertinputStreamToString function once.

```
public static String convertinputStreamToString(InputStream ists)
        throws IOException {
    if (ists != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    ists, "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = r1.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            ists.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```